# Select a particular value of JSON string using MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I have a table that looks like this

```
+------+------------------------------------+
|  id  |              details               |
+------+------------------------------------+
|   1  | {"price":"24.99","currency":"USD"} |
+------+------------------------------------+
```

Is it possible to, with a single MySQL select statement, obtain the value of price 24.99?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search JSON data in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411210/how-to-search-json-data-in-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve JSON data from mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701579/how-to-retrieve-json-data-from-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can using [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract)

It probably should be like:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(details, "$.price")
FROM table_name
```

or another form:

```
SELECT details->"$.price"
FROM table_name
```

(*I don't have MySql to test it*)

Note that the price in your JSON stored as a string, not a number and you probably would want to cast it to a [DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html).

Comment: Ahh MySQL 5.7...now to wait for Google Cloud to support it :)