# Mysql json datatype count and groupby

Tags: mysql, json

So since mysql 5.7 i am now able to use the json datatype which is nice when your working with frameworks like angularjs.

Now since im fairly new to this (and this datatype is also fairly new) i was wondering if i could make some simple operations on that dataset.

For instance i have saved a json in my database where each object contains the following fields:

```
name
country
phone_num
```

What i wish to do is i wish to sum how many that lives in each country normally a select like this would work

```
select country, count(*) as num_residents from mytable
```

However im not quite sure how to use this sort of select statement on a table that has a json datatype.

Can anyone help me out?

**Update**

Okay so my table looks like this:

```
id  int(11) AI PK
date_created    timestamp
data    json
schema_id   int(11)
```

The data looks like this:

```
[{"A": 1, "B": "Debra", "C": "Peters", "D": "dpeters0@accuweather.com", "E": "Female", "F": "Tsagaan-Ovoo"}, {"A": 2, "B": "Marc", "C": "Rasmussen", "D": "Marc@test.dk", "E": "Male", "F": "Copenhagen"}]
```

And i am trying the following sql statement:

```
    SELECT
  data,
  JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.F")        AS country,
  count(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.F")) AS num_residents
FROM kpi_data
WHERE schema_id = 39
GROUP BY country, data
```

But  sadly i get this result:

[image]

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701579/how-to-retrieve-json-data-from-mysql

Comment: Marc, take a look at `JSON_EXTRACT` function. You can do something like `select JSON_EXTRACT(doc, "$.country") as country, count(JSON_EXTRACT(doc, "$.country")) as num_residents from mytable`

Comment: @algor ive updated my post can you take a look at what im doing wrong?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen I can see that data actually is array of 2 documents (Debra and Marc), try to access values by index: $[0].F or $[1].F (I have not tried this approach since I have no access to db now)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly you are storing all the JSON in one row, if you want to query the data like this each resident should have it's own row of his/her own JSON:

```
*other_fields*, {"A": 1, "B": "Debra", "C": "Peters", "D": "dpeters0@accuweather.com", "E": "Female", "F": "Tsagaan-Ovoo"}
*other_fields*, {"A": 2, "B": "Marc", "C": "Rasmussen", "D": "Marc@test.dk", "E": "Male", "F": "Copenhagen"}
```

Secondly you don't need to count the extracted data, you just need to count the rows for each country extracted. This will do:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.F") AS country,
       COUNT(*) AS num_residents
```

Thirdly, you don't want to `GROUP BY data` at all as this is presumably unique per resident. This will leave you with a group for each row. I think you just want:

```
GROUP BY country
```

Putting it all together:

```
  SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.F") AS country,
         COUNT(*) AS num_residents
    FROM kpi_data
   WHERE schema_id = 39
GROUP BY country
```

For decent performance, you may consider placing an secondary index on the extracted country.. see [DOCS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes-virtual-columns.html)

Comment: Is it because my data is encapsulated in an array like this [{}] that i am unable to query on it if so how should i store the data ? to store it correctly?

Comment: Also do you know how i can make a where statement?

Comment: My suggestion is right there after 'Firstly... '; Store each object in your array as a separate row. No need for the array after that.

Comment: Updated to include your WHERE.