# Using json_extract where data has no key mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, json

In my database one field is `video_status_ids` json type column, which should be many to many relation with videos table, but for me, it is now in videos table only and the records are like

`[2, 6, 9, 11]`, `[2, 4, 7, 9]` etc etc now I want to get records group by 2, 4, 6 7, 9 etc is it possible, may be using `JSON_EXTRACT` and `JSON_CONTAINS`, I tried using like

```
SELECT `videos`.`id`, `videos.link`,
  JSON_EXTRACT(`videos`.`video_status_ids`, '*') as status 
FROM `videos` GROUP BY status
```

it is not working, actually getting wrong results, getting something like {key:value} in video_status_ids column which is not in database.

I would like to get records group by video_status_id. so if there are records with

`[2, 6, 9, 11]`, `[2, 4, 7, 9]`, `[3, 7, 10]`, `[3, 8, 10]` I would like to group by with status_id 3 and status_id 3.

may be this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347443/mysql-json-datatype-count-and-groupby) describe my problem, but I do not have key value pair.

Comment: Please show a bit more of that Json, so we can see it in context.

Comment: @GolezTrol thank you for your response, I have added a screenshot with demo records, please have a look at it.

Comment: It's not clear what you want the result of your query to be. Can you show an example?

Comment: @BillKarwin sorry for late response I left the office that time, I have edited my question, if still need something, please let me know.

Comment: "group by with status_id 3 and status_id 3" is not any more clear. Sorry, good luck! I'm moving on to read some other person's question.

Comment: @BillKarwin sorry I think I could explain better, see I have combination of status_id in video_status_ids column, now I want to retrieve records which have status_id 2 and 3, may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347443/mysql-json-datatype-count-and-groupby) question describe my problem, but I do not have key value pair.