# Decode json data while querying data from mysql database

Tags: mysql, json, phpmyadmin, decode, encode

Is it possible to retrieve decoded data from a mysql db column in which data is saved as json encoded text ie. instead of fetching json encoded text from the db and decoding it separately, is there any method to fetch decoded data from the select query itself?
Any help? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701579/how-to-retrieve-json-data-from-mysql. Check once

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve JSON data from mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701579/how-to-retrieve-json-data-from-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

The answer linked by jyoti mishra is quite good; MySQL handles JSON data internally now and `json_extract` is definitely the preferred solution if you're on MySQL 5.7 or later.

However, if you're not, you can use the [phpMyAdmin "Transformation" feature](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/transformations.html#transformations) to modify the displayed output when you're viewing through phpMyAdmin.

To start, you have to have at least partially configured the "[phpMyAdmin configuration storage](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage)". From the table's Structure tab, "Change" the column containing the JSON data, then look for the "Browser display transformation" dropdown and select JSON. See this photo for an example:

[image: Transformation dropdown]