# How to query MySQL Json Array

Tags: mysql, json

A MySQL table has a JSON column containing a large amount of JSON data.

For example:

```
SELECT nodes From Table LIMIT 1;
```

results in:

```
'{"data": {"id": "Node A", "state": true, "details": [{"value": "Value","description": "Test"}, {"value": "Value2", "description": "Test2"}, {"value": "Value 7", "description": "Test 7"}, {"value": "Value 9", "description": "Test 9"}]}}'
```

How can I write queries that return rows in accordance with the following examples:

1. Where Node A state is True. In this case "Node A" is the value of key "id" and "state" contains True or False.
2. Where "value" is "Value2" or where "description" is "Test2." Note that these values are in a list that contains key value pairs.

Comment: Please look at this link might it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701579/how-to-retrieve-json-data-from-mysql

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you can make a direct MySQL query to achieve above task. You will have to load all the string data from MySQL db then parse this string to get JSON object upon which you can perform your custom query operation to get your output.

But here in this case i will suggest you to use MongoDB which will be an ideal database storage solution and you can make direct queries.