# SQL CONCAT to JSON

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I am trying to achieve the following JSON result (looping trough the rows in the database):

```js
[{
"title":"Pasta E Vino Petraglia",
"image_url":"image",
"subtitle":"description 1",
"buttons":[
{
"type": "url",
"caption": "More Details",
"url": "https://domain"
}
]
},{
"title":"La Pasta",
"image_url":"image",
"subtitle":"description 2",
"buttons":[
{
"type": "url",
"caption": "More Details",
"url": "https://domain"
}
]
}]
```

And I want to do it directly within the SQL query. I wrote this line, but something is not right and I cannot figure it out what is wrong and what I should do.

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('[{',GROUP_CONCAT(concat_ws(',',concat('"title":"',name,'"'),concat('"image_url":"',image,'"'),concat('"subtitle":"',info,'"'),CONCAT('"buttons":[{',GROUP_CONCAT(concat_ws(',',concat('"type":"url"'),concat('"caption":"More Details"'),concat('"url":"https://domain"')) SEPARATOR '},{'),'}]')
) SEPARATOR '},{'),'}]') FROM `Places`
```

Result:

> Invalid use of group function

I am not sure that this is the best way to achieve what I am trying to do, so any other ideas are also appreciated.

I am using MySQL with the MyISAM engine.

**UPDATE**

I have noticed that when I do not go nested and creating only the simple object, it works fine, and this execute correctly.

```
SELECT CONCAT('[{',GROUP_CONCAT(concat_ws(',',concat('"title":"',name,'"'),concat('"image_url":"',image,'"'),concat('"subtitle":"',info,'"')
) SEPARATOR '},{'),'}]')
```

So actually the second concat_group is where the issue is, or the place I am concating, this piece of code

```
CONCAT('"buttons":[{',GROUP_CONCAT(concat_ws(',',concat('"type":"url"'),concat('"caption":"More Details"'),concat('"url":"https://domain"')) SEPARATOR '},{'),'}]')
```

**Database Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `Places` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(22) DEFAULT NULL,
  `info` varchar(197) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subtype` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(140) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(110) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Sample DATA**

```
INSERT INTO `Places` (`id`, `name`, `info`, `type`, `subtype`, `keywords`, `image`, `url`) VALUES
(1, 'Pasta E Vino Petraglia', 'description 1', 'Restaurant', 'Italian', 'pasta ', 'https://lostinplovdiv.com/timthumb.php?src=/media/images/aefb966533cc0bffe40b9d1e14ca0c4c7018de3891db83ccf721cf761df9359e.png&w=460&h=&zc=0', 'https://www.facebook.com/Pasta-E-Vino-Petraglia-194285454717186/'),
(2, 'La Pasta', 'description 2', 'Restaurant', 'Italian', 'pasta', 'https://lostinplovdiv.com/timthumb.php?src=/media/images/291359f1fa156815c2c9632033e23b8c9598885783faca803096e6bebc4c46c6.png&w=460&h=&zc=0', 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g295391-d11889447-Reviews-La_pasta-Plovdiv_Plovdiv_Province.html'),
(3, 'Brick House', 'BRICK HOUSE description 3', 'Restaurant', 'Burger', 'burger', 'https://lostinplovdiv.com/timthumb.php?src=/media/images/c732a45b8f3b2aec8dfb976f8c3609af7c29d16799ffc73998f09657ad9bb314.png&w=460&h=&zc=0', 'https://bg-bg.facebook.com/brickkhousee/posts');
```

Comment: What result are you getting? It'll be easier to help if you show the result you are getting.

Comment: please label the db engine you are using, it's not the same the way to concat strings for each technology

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve JSON data from mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701579/how-to-retrieve-json-data-from-mysql)

Comment: Just update the missing info

Comment: @Muhammad Saqlain, the duplicate you mention is not the same as mine

Comment: Post your table schema, and sample data.

Comment: Here is a link to a data end schema.  Will post it also in the main post https://paiza.io/projects/w8d9ndxZD95ct-ph4N69tA?language=mysql

Comment: It is not the best idea to do all this concatenation on MySQL side, you should better fetch data and concatenate whatever you need on application side. So far you problem is `GROUP_CONCAT` can be used only when you `GROUP BY` data. But you don't.

Comment: So update your expected result to match sample data you've posted. That will help  us to understand your final goal. I suspect you want to get mysql response as json - which is impossible. Mysql response is always kind plain text, and some columns can be kind json strings.

Comment: There is nothing to update in the expected result. It is exactly as simple as that. Basically there is interaction with 3 of the fields in the the database (name, image and info), the rest in the JSON is hardcoded (for now).

Comment: I dont mind having it as a plain text... further manipulation of the result will be done after that.

Comment: You still do not understand - it is impossible what you expect to get.

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure about your final goal.

As I already mentioned in comments you should better do all this json transformation on application side.

So far t seem you don't need `GROUP_CONCAT` at all.

Here is the closest approach you can get IMHO:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/125235/12

```
SELECT CONCAT('{\"title\":\"',name,'\", \"image_url\":\"',image,'\", \"subtitle\":\"',info,
              '\"buttons\":[{\"type\": \"url\",\"caption\": \"More Details\",\"url\": \"https://domain"}]\"}')
FROM Places;


SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('[',CONCAT('{\"title\":\"',name,'\", \"image_url\":\"',image,'\", \"subtitle\":\"',info,
              '\"buttons\":[{\"type\": \"url\",\"caption\": \"More Details\",\"url\": \"https://domain"}]\"}'),
                    ']')
FROM Places
```

But please check - last query - does not return proper wrapped json array!
That what I've mean you can play and wrap this select with another select with concat having this  one as subquery. But whole this approach has very wrong architecture and you should avoid such big transformation on sql side.

Comment: I see your point now. I think I should try doing you with the result. Thanks fr your help.