# Count data by value in mysql 8 json

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-8.0

I new in mysql 8. I wanted to count data by value in JSON data. The data is look like this:

```
{"13": "A", "14": "B", "15": "A"}
```

For example, I want to count data where the value is "A". So if using that data, I will get 2. How to do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701579/how-to-retrieve-json-data-from-mysql Check this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do like this,

```
select  json_length(json_search('{"13": "A", "14": "B", "15": "A"}','all','A')) ;
```

**Explaination**:

**json_search**

1. First argument is a json string.
2. Second argument is criteria. 'all' means look for all matches.
3. Third argument is search string. here, 'A'.

**json_length**

1. Return size of the json.

Please refer [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html) for more info.

Comment: You don't actually need the call to `json_extract` for this code. `json_search` can work equally well on objects.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. It work like what I expected