# Select value for a key in json in specific column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

In MySQL, how do I select ONLY the values for nationality key in the jsonInfo column for all rows?

```
userid  displayName jsonInfo
11  John Nakamura   {"nationality":"ROK", "build": "average", "height":"511", "eyeColor":"brown", "ethnicity":"Asian"}
12  Jose Hernandez  {"nationality": "El Salvador", "build": "average", "height":"510", "eyeColor":"brown", "ethnicity":"Latino"}
13  Bobby Simmons   {"nationality": "USA", "build": "big", "height":"601", "eyeColor":"blue", "ethnicity":"Caucasian"}
```

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701579/how-to-retrieve-json-data-from-mysql

Comment: Think what you're looking for is `json_extract(jsonInfo, '$.nationality') AS Nationality`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve JSON data from MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701579/how-to-retrieve-json-data-from-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT jsonInfo->>'$.nationnality' FROM tbl
```