# In MySql, how do I check if a row with json field has a key that contains a specific text?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-json

So let's say I have a row that looks like

```
id json_data
1  { ... }
2  { ... }
3  { ... }
```

I want to select the rows that have a key which contains a string `abc`.
I tried to use something like

`SELECT * FROM table1 t where JSON_EXTRACT(t.json_data,...`

but wasn't able to complete the query because I wasn't sure how to add this condition.

Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve JSON data from MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701579/how-to-retrieve-json-data-from-mysql)

Comment: No because I am trying to check the Key value, not retrieve the value with the key

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with some example raw data and what your expected result set should be. You have a lot of `...` in your question, which leaves a lot of room for interpretation.

Comment: How much overlap will there be with keys/values matching `abc`? You could treat the column as a raw string and search `WHERE t.json_data LIKE '%abc%'`, and possibly manually filter out false positives.

Comment: Have you tried [JSON_SEARCH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search)?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to look at the top level keys, this is simply:

```
json_keys(json_data) like '%abc%'
```